# The Ultimate Number Sequence Puzzle

Tags: steganography

Alright, so number sequence puzzles have been falling off a little bit. Puzzlers have been at a loss at how to combat this for some time, and I wanted to try to give it some thought. Right away, I thought of sequences related to pi and what-not. In trying to come up with something, however, everything was too obvious or too hard. Later, I tried e (Euler's constant), but with the same results. For all my efforts, I couldn't come up with anything. On the whole, I was stumped. Once more, I tried to come up with something brilliant and clever, and this time I succeeded! Laws of nature sure make great puzzles (I dare not say more). So, enjoy this spectacular number puzzle!

> 234, 98123, 53491, 1239, 0984132, 2, -932, 542701, 90231, 45, 87610, 43619082, 3149, ???

What is the pattern?

Comment: Happy April Fool's Day, everyone! Just thought I'd spread a little silliness.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, at least part of the pattern is

> that the first letters of the sentences spell APRIL FOOLS.

But

> those sentences look a bit more constrained than they need to be just for that, so it's possible that I've missed something else. (The numbers, though, look a *lot* like the result of a keyboard-mash -- lots of short increasing and decreasing sequences, e.g. -- and I bet there's nothing useful in them regardless.)

Comment: Yep, this one is super-simple. Just a little goofiness to match the unicorns today :) Will retag my question to reflect its true nature.

Comment: I wondered whether I should refrain from solving it out loud...

Comment: Ah, fine as is. Probably would have accumulated some close votes from annoyed mathematicians if you hadn't. Also, I only spent about 2 mins on the puzzle itself, so it's not like you're messing up well-laid plans or anything.

Comment: Pro tip: If you're looking to fool people with random fake numbers, you might want to avoid certain things such as unnecessary leading 0's, and sequences of adjacent digits which just scream "button mashing"...

Comment: Indeed. But I don't think Brandon was trying very hard to fool people :-).

Comment: Haha not very hard.